# jquery how to access data in li

Tags: jquery

I have list like this

```
<ul id="list">
    <li url="book/love">Love</li>
    <li url="book/cook">Food</li>
    <li url="book/policy">Policy</li>
    <li url="book/child">Child</li>
     ...............
    <li url="book/funny">Funny</li>
</ul>
```

How i can get data in `url` of this `list`?

my script like this

```
console.log($("#list li").attr("url")[1]); //It's should show **book/cook** but it's return undefined
```

how i can get this data ?

Comment: do you only want value of index `1` ?

Comment: I got answer ready from some has answer me first time but now don't know why that he/she remove his answer.

Answer (score 2):

By using `:eq(indexNumber)` you can access values of elements by index. Else you can create a array of all the values of li and then use index to access the value. Below are the two solutions.

**Solution 1** :Using `:eq()`

```
console.log($("#list li:eq(1)").attr("url");
```

`eq(1)` stands for index one as the indexes starts from 0, your second element will have index 1.

**Solution 2:** Create a array of values from the li and then access them

```
    var liArray = [];

    $.each('#list li',function(i,v){
       liArray.push($(this).attr('url'));
    });

   console.log(liArray[0]);
   ...
   ...
   ...
   console.log(liArray[4]);
   ...
```

Comment: Liked the solution 1 approach.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//console.log("console " +$('#list li:eq(2)').attr('url'));

var ulli = $('#list li');


$.each(ulli, function(index, value) {


  console.log($(this).attr('url')) //if you want to use data('url') your html should look like <li data-url="book/love">Love</li>

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li url="book/love">Love</li>
  <li url="book/cook">Food</li>
  <li url="book/policy">Policy</li>
  <li url="book/child">Child</li>
  ...............
  <li url="book/funny">Funny</li>
</ul>
```

Do like this.

Use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Comment: Great formatting here. @guradio how to add demo snippets like you did.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list li').each(function()
{
   console.log($(this).attr('url'));
});
```

Working fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/17vsnz13/